# Type for icon in React Component's Interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Using Radix-UI's [Accordion](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/accordion#accordion), the reusable component is changed in order to accept as props an icon.

The interface:

```
interface AccordionTriggerProps {
  trigger: string;
  icon?: StyledComponent<
    React.FunctionComponent<
      React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & {
        title?: string | undefined;
      }
    >,
    never
  >;
}
```

The component that uses the above interface:

```
const AccordionTrigger = ({ trigger, icon }: AccordionTriggerProps) => (
  <header>
    {icon}
    {trigger}
  </header>
);
```

The component reused in other place like following:

```
<AccordionTrigger trigger="Learn" icon={<StyledLearnIcon />} />
```

It works fine, it renders the component but it still says there is an error for the icon:

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type
> 'StyledComponent<FunctionComponent<SVGProps & { title?:
> string | undefined; }>, never, {}, never>'

Any idea why and how to fix it?

How the icon is defined:

```
import { ReactComponent as LearnIcon } from 'svgs/learn.svg';

export const StyledLearnIcon = styled(LearnIcon)`
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;
```

Comment: have you tried to just define the AccordionTriggerProps icon property as "Element" ?

Comment: @JacckMark I've tried and now the error says: `Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 164 more.`

Comment: also setting `icon?: icon?: Element<unknown, unknown>;` removes the error message from component but it says in the interface that `Type 'Element' is not generic`